# Updating progress bar using progress percentage sent by a cmd process

Tags: c#, asynchronous, event-handling, progress-bar, iprogress

I am new to C# windows form. I want to update a progress bar in my program using the standard output data which is received from a cmd process.

At first it wouldn't let me update the bar and gave me the `can not access the bar from multiple threads` error. So I went and started the process asynchronously and hooked a handler to `OutputDataReceived` and used `process.BeginOutputReadLine()` to read the data async line by line and also passed an `IProgress<ProgressReportDataModel>` into the handler which would call another event to update progress bar.

The only thing is that the progress percentage data all comes in one line and when the `OutputDataReceived` event is called the process has already finished progress bar jumps to 100%. How can I update progress bar here?

The code below is the method which is called by `Task.Run()`:

```
private int FlasherRun(string args, IProgress<ProgressReportDataModel> progress)
{
    ProgressReportDataModel report = new(); // for resetting bar when finished

    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

    startInfo.FileName = programmerFileName;
    startInfo.Arguments = args;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process.StartInfo = startInfo;

    process.OutputDataReceived +=
        (Object _sender, DataReceivedEventArgs _args)
            => FlasherOutputHandler(_sender, _args, progress);

    process.Start();

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

    process.WaitForExit();

    // Reset progress bar
    report.progressPercentageComplete = 0;
    progress.Report(report);

    return process.ExitCode;
}
```

and the function below is the handler for received data:

```
private void FlasherOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine,
    IProgress<ProgressReportDataModel> progress)
{
    ProgressReportDataModel report = new ProgressReportDataModel();

    // extract percentage value from outLine.Data and then
    
    report.progressPercentageComplete = percentageValue;
    report.progressMessages = someMessage;
    progress.Report(report);
}
```

and the event handler below is hooked to `progress.ProgressChanged` before calling the first function async:

```
private void ReportProgressEvent(object? sender, ProgressReportDataModel e)
{
    progressBar.Value = e.progressPercentageComplete;
    messagesTextBox.Text += e.progressMessages;
}
```

and here is the method that instantiates `Progress<>` and calls the FlasherRun method async.

```
private async void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Progress<ProgressReportDataModel> progress = new Progress<ProgressReportDataModel>();
        progress.ProgressChanged += ReportProgressEvent;

        string flasherCMD = "some command";
        int exitCode = 0;

        exitCode = await Task.Run(() => FlasherRun(flasherCMD, progress));
        if (exitCode != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // exceptions are handled here
    }
}
```

I have tried reading the data which comes from standard output using `process.StandardOutput.Read()` method one character at a time in a while() loop and calling a progress update when there is a new percentage available inside the incoming data, but that just seems to not call the progress updater event in the midst of reading, and after the reader is finished and the while() loop is exited it calls the updater 20 times with the 100% value which is the last value that comes through the streamreader.

Comment: Could you edit the question and include the method that instantiates the `IProgress<ProgressReportDataModel>` and calls the `FlasherRun`? My guess is that the `process.WaitForExit();` is the source of the problem.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I have done the edit that you asked. what is your opinion?

Comment: My guess was wrong. The `FlasherRun` is running on the `ThreadPool`, not on the UI thread. So I have no idea what causes your problem.